# RxJava as an Eventbus between service and activity

Tags: android, events, socket.io, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have gone through several tutorials such as [this](https://lorentzos.com/rxjava-as-event-bus-the-right-way-10a36bdd49ba#.k2tzbjabu) and [this](http://blog.kaush.co/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/) on the usage of `Rxjava` as an `EventBus`. However, they do not solve my problem.

I am making a chat app using my own custom nodejs server and socket.io. Authorization is done via retrofit (with gson). The user should receive messages even if the app is switched off, hence the connection to socket.io is maintained through a perennial service, which will relay information to the activity IF it is displayed to the user, else it simply shows a notification and writes to SQL db (TODO). My `Service` receives a call from `socket.io` and parses the payload. When that happens, it needs to send a message to the activity along with the payload received.

MyEventBus.class

```
public class MyRxBus {

    private static MyRxBus instance;

    private PublishSubject<Object> subject = PublishSubject.create();

    public static MyRxBus instanceOf() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyRxBus();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Pass any event down to event listeners.
     */
    public void setString(Object object) {
        subject.onNext(object);
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to this Observable. On event, do something 
     * e.g. replace a fragment
     */
    public Observable<Object> getEvents() {
        return subject;
    }
}
```

SocketService Class

```
public class SocketService extends Service {
    private Socket mSocket;
    public SocketService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("SERVICE ","SOCKET SERVICE WAS CALLED");
        mSocket=SocketSingleton.getSocket("8080");
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT,onConnect);
        mSocket.on("new_message",onNewMessage);
        mSocket.connect();
    }


    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            Log.d("Received from socket ",args[0].toString());
            try {
                final JSONObject object = new JSONObject((String) args[0]);
                //Send this object to all subscribers
                //TODO: add rxjava eventbus to 1)add info to db, 2)update activity IF it is displayed
                MyRxBus.instanceOf()
                    .setEvent(object);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
  //some other functions (not related at all)

}
```

MainActivity.class

```
   public class MainActivity extends VesicaActivity {
    private Socket mSocketOne;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private List<ChatMessage> mMessages = new ArrayList<ChatMessage>();
    private List<String> mListOfUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
    Boolean isNodeOne;
    String username;
    private JSONArray arrayOfUsers=null;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private Boolean _isConnected=false;
    private String socketIdtoSend;

    @BindView(R.id.et_text)EditText etText;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_user_list)TextView tvListUsers;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_status)TextView tvStatus;
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)Toolbar toolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.et_self_destruct_time)EditText etSelfDestructTimer;
    @BindView(R.id.cb_self_destruct)CheckBox cbSelfDestruct;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar()!=null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        tvStatus.setText("checking connection...");
        username = Constants.getUsername();
        Integer portNumber = Constants.getPortNumber();
        socketIdtoSend = getIntent().getStringExtra("socketId");
        mMessages.add(createMessage("Sample Name","Sample Text",0));
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new ChatAdapter(mMessages, username);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        //-----------------------------------------------------------------

        MyRxBus.instanceOf()
                .getEvents()
                .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Object o) {
                       final JSONObject object = new JSONObject((String) o)
                       ChatMessage message = createMessage(object.getString("user")
                               ,Encryption.Decrypt(object.getString("message"))
                               ,object.getInt("selfDestructTime"));
                       mMessages.add(message);
                       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," new message received ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    }


    public ChatMessage createMessage(String user, String message, Integer time){
        return new ChatMessage.ChatMessageBuilder()
                .message(message)
                .user(user)
                .type("newMessage")
                .selfDestructTime(time)
                .sendToSocketId(socketIdtoSend)
                .build();
    }


    public void showDialogBoxToClearHistory(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Wipe Chat History")
                .setMessage("This will delete the entire chat history of this thread. It is irreversible. Do you want to continue?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete
                        mMessages.clear();
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cleared entire history", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Skip", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       try{
                           dialog.dismiss();
                       }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false)
                .show();
    }

    private void ScrollToBottom(){
        mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount());
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error
 `rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

that points to
`at com.example.varun.vesica.eventbus.MyRxBus.setEvent(MyRxBus.java:26)`

I am aware that observables and observers can be set to emit/ observe of different threads, however after lot of trial and error, I have given up and need some help.

Any help/ links will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maintainin connection all time will drain user's battery. You should consider using push notification when device is blocked or app is minimized.
When you subscribe to Observable in Activity, save Subscription and close it in onPause, otherwise there will be lingering connections caused by device rotation. 
Consider using GreenRobot event bus instead of reinventing the wheel, it is very convenient library for connecting Service and Activity: http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/11/28/android-how-to-use-the-greenrobot-eventbus/

Comment: Socket.io will not drain the battery much. If i use push notifications, it defeats the purpose of using socket.io for my chat protocol. There are several disadvantages of simply using GCM for chat apps.

The additional benefits of RxJava are far too much to ignore compared to GreenRobot, and I am already using it to bind my text views.

Yes subscriptions will be removed in the onPause. I have disabled device rotation (like most apps).

Comment: you mean Butterknife? There is no EventBus in Activity's code

Comment: Butterknife is for just view binding. RxJava can be used as text watchers on text views. Sorry for the typo above. Basically I am using RxJava for a lot of things in the app, and want to stick with it since it can do whatever GreenRobot can do and more. As an example, I have used RxJava in login page for the app, which makes the UI extremely responsive and my code is shorter than a traditional approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and `Toast.makeText()` on whatever arbitrary thread invoked `setEvent()`/`setString()`.
When you subscribe to your `getEvents()` observable with the goal of updating Android UI, you need to observe on the main thread scheduler:

```
    MyRxBus.instanceOf()
            .getEvents()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object o) {
                   final JSONObject object = new JSONObject((String) o)
                   ChatMessage message = createMessage(object.getString("user")
                           ,Encryption.Decrypt(object.getString("message"))
                           ,object.getInt("selfDestructTime"));
                   mMessages.add(message);
                   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," new message received ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I will try this out, but the error is being thrown on the setEvent() called in the service class, not the activity class that consumes the event.

Comment: I tried a similar approach by calling `onNext()` from a random thread and subscribing to show a Toast and got the same error. The stack trace points to the event source - the service class in your case, and has a "Caused by:" that points to the subscription's `Toast` invocation.